# Responsive featherlight iframes width

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox, featherlight.js

I'm using the featherlight lightbox to open iframes with different widths, please see the 1st 2 links on the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/sm123456/d5Lvw1rs/

The issue is that I seem I cant seem to be able to make the iframe responsive ie. when the browser window goes below the iframe width, the iframe should switch to 100%.

I've tried the code below which should work great, but doesn't, even when removing `data-featherlight-iframe-height="575" data-featherlight-iframe-width="800".`

```
data-featherlight-iframe-style="width: 100% !important; max-width: 800px !important;"
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you fix your problem? Because for me, your JSFiddle is doing exactly what you want. As soon as the window is smaller than 920px, it's going to 100% the window width.

Comment: No havent fixed it yet! But there are 2 different sized (width) iframes.. 1 is 800px and 1 is 1350px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the documentation, I found out you can add a custom class to the lightbox using the `data-featherlight-variant="classname"` attribute. Using this attribute, I added a different class to both the 800px and the 1350px one. Using that class, I applied the style. Check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75r2g3x9/) to see it in action.

For the 800px width one:

> data-featherlight-variant="custom-class-800"

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .custom-class-800,
  .custom-class-800 .featherlight-content{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .custom-class-800 .featherlight-content .featherlight-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

For the 1350px width one:

> data-featherlight-variant="custom-class-1350"

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
  .custom-class-1350,
  .custom-class-1350 .featherlight-content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75r2g3x9/)

Comment: Thanks! ..but how about the iframe in the fiddle which is 1350 px width? This solution only caters for the 800px iframe

Comment: I will create another media query for the other iframe.

Comment: Added CSS for the other one

Comment: Hi Yes sorry but isnt working not even in the fiddle (the iframe at width 1350 is not effected) im using the latest ff version 106.0.3

Comment: Hi @JimWids I have found an easier solution, see the JSFiddle for a working example.

Comment: @JimWids did you notice the new solution?

Comment: thanks brother yes thats the perfect solution, I searched for a way to add a class but couldnt find it... thanks so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: it seems im not able to give u the 50+ points? but many thanks!

Comment: Yes the bounty unfortunately expired and only payed out half, but no problem glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Hey [@JimWids](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10782385/jimwids)

Try to use that CSS:-

```
.featherlight-iframe .featherlight-content{
        /* dimensions: 1140px prevents iframe from spanning the full width of the browser */
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 1140px;

        /* spacing */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .featherlight-iframe .featherlight-inner{
        /* positioning */
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;

        /* dimensions */
    
        width: 100%;
    }
    .featherlight .featherlight-inner:after{
        /* dimensions */
        content: "";
        float: left;
        width: 80%;
    height:80%;
        padding-top: 57%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

#### Here is that code:- [JS_Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSDmark/x7zwg2j0/)

Comment: Thanks but the smaller iframe (900px) will now stretch larger than 900px, surely the same with the larger one too but im on a small screen so its not evident to me

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
  .featherlight .featherlight-content {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .featherlight .featherlight-image {
      width: 100% !important;
      object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```